# how to best store timestamp or date in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I need to store last-push-date in Cassandra and wondering what the best way is as it is just one column and one row. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table which has a `bucket` as partition key.
This way with a constant bucket ID of 0 you can update that value by just `INSERT` operations. This is called "upsert" in Cassandra.

```
 CREATE TABLE last_push_date (
    bucket INT,
    last_push_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (bucket)
);
```

To insert and update the same `last_push_date` value you can use just insert commands using bucket 0:

```
INSERT INTO last_push_date (bucket, last_push_date) VALUES (0, '2017-11-11');
INSERT INTO last_push_date (bucket, last_push_date) VALUES (0, '2017-11-13');
```

Selecting `last_push_date` will return result of last insert:

```
 SELECT * FROM last_push_date WHERE bucket = 0;

 bucket | last_push_date
--------+----------------
      0 |     2017-11-13
```

If you want to have another `last_push_date` just use another bucket ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are really asking for... But i'll give it a shot.

I think you have already answered your question - there is only one column and one row, which won't have any real impact on the way Cassandra operates. In my experience there is not any best specific way of storing this kind of information - Cassandra is made for quickly being able to store data and has internal ways of dealing with consistency and replication.